# Close the "Sponsored session" window after Teamviewer disconnected

Tags: autohotkey

the following simple script is for closing the window "sponsored session" after the teamviewer(remote control client) disconnected, but i found the script does actually not working ? need help, thanks very much

```
#Persistent
#NoEnv
WinWait Sponsored session
WinKill
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close a window with Autohotkey as soon as it pops up, we have to create a loop (to do it multiple times), wait for a window to show up and kill it then. We detect the window through its title (here: "Sponsored Session")

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#NoEnv

Loop, {
    WinWait Sponsored session
    WinKill 
    sleep 100
}
```

The `SetTitleMatchMode, 2` does a partial match on the window title, so it may be kill more then expected if not used with caution (e.g. it will kill an browser if the title is part of the pagetitle).

The title of the target window can easily be detected with the "Window Spy" tool, which comes with AHK and can be used via the tray menu icon of any running AHK script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunally, the script was failed, its all my fault, i did not explain my needs as well (sorry for my English): i need to close(also could kill) the pop tips titled "sponsored session" when each time the teamviewer session disconnected (and it will pop out a tips), so i need to use the winwait command and close it

Comment: Winwait added. But i think there is a misunderstanding about it. Winwait stops the script and waits for the window to appear. It is NOT a trigger. So you still need the loop to do it repeatly.

Comment: Thanks for the add, still failed to wait then close the popup window, so im very confused about why and how to make it works

Comment: Maybe your Window name isn't an exact match, i added `setTitleMatchMode, 2`

Comment: While your script is running you have an AHK icon in the tray bar. You can right click that icon to geht infos and helpfull tools, which might help here.

Comment: after adding the `setTitleMatchMode, 2` ,it still does not working,so im thinking about what about try another matchmode? yes i have read some of the basic script,but due to my poor strenth, i dont know all of them as well, so i was looking for help in here, thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: MatchMode 2 is already the one catching the most, make sure your script is running (there is a icon in the tray bar) and use the "Window Spy" tool to get the correct title of the target window.

Comment: Did rewrite the answer completly to improve general qualitiy

Comment: yes im pretty sure the title is correct, and i am sure the script is running, becoz it just closed this webpage whether its active or not active, and yes , tried your rewrited script, also failed, oh my ,,,

Answer (score -2):

Using `Loop` will cause a load on the CPU. So I made it resident in `#Persistent` and initialized with `reload` after processing.

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance  Force

WinWait, Sponsored session{
    WinActivate, Sponsored session
    Sleep, 500
    Send, {Enter}
    reload
}
```